# FROM_DAYS() not giving expected output[MySQL]

Tags: mysql

The official documentation says that [FROM_DAYS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-days) returns a valid date given number of days N.

Then why is this happening ?
[image: trying out from_days(N)]

Should it not display the valid dates for days less than a year, like
from_days(5) = 0000-01-05 ?

**Edit :** I was solving a question which went as "Find the period an employee has worked given their date of joining and report the duration in the format years,months,days"

And I was using the following query :

```
select Emp_Name,    
date_format(from_days(datediff(curdate(),Date_of_Join)),"%y") as year,  
date_format(from_days(datediff(curdate(),Date_of_Join)),"%m") as month,   
date_format(from_days(datediff(curdate(),Date_of_Join)),"%d") as day 
from EMPLOYEE;
```

It was in these results that I discovered this discrepancy.

Comment: The Question is what does `N` represent in the `FROM_DAYS(N)`

Comment: I did not get your point @Bsienn, the doc says that N is the number of days and it calculates the date from year 0000.

Answer (score 0):

As the MySql [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) reports:

> The function is not designed for use with dates before the advent of
>   the Gregorian calendar in October 1582. Results will not be reliable
>   since it doesn't account for the lost days when the calendar changed
>   from the Julian calendar.

So, if you set the argument of this function with a small number (around N < 1582*365), it is not reliable.

Comment: Hmm, @kiks73, I don't think so that is the reason for this.I have tried multiple other values and they all give the correct answer except for the case where days < 366

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue when computing age of patients. I noted that when using FROM_DAYS(N) , When N is less than 366 it won't return correct number of months and days.
Solution: Add 366 for Months and Days part. e.g

```
SET @age_of_patient_years = DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(NOW(), "2023-07-22")), '%Y') + 0;

SET @age_of_patient_months= DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(NOW(), "2023-07-22") +366 ), '%m') - 1;

SET @age_of_patient_days = DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(NOW(), "2023-09-22") +366 ), '%d') + 0;

SELECT @age_of_patient_years,@age_of_patient_months,@age_of_patient_days;
```